# AJAX - 404 with Slim PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, slim

I'm getting a 404 (Not found) in the console when trying to get data with AJAX in my Slim PHP application. Here's the error message :

```
http://localhost:8888/Project/mods/public/edit-mod/ajax/get-categories?gameID=1  404 (Not Found)
```

Here's the route defined in a routes.php file (that is correctly included, all the other routes are working) :

```
$app->get("/ajax/get-categories/", function() use ($app, $User, $Game, $Mod){

    //Fetch data and echo it
});
```

Finally, here's how I'm calling the AJAX page in the JS script :

```
$.get("ajax/get-categories", {gameID: gameID}, function(data){

    //Do something with data    
});
```

I tried changing the Slim route to "ajax/get-categories/" (without the leading `/` ) but it didn't change anything, and I also try a bunch of different paths for the AJAX call (in the JS script) but nothing worked, I always get the 404 no matter what.

When I'm calling only `ajax/get-categories`  in my script, it seems to be appending the current page (ex `edit-mod/` ) to the route, maybe that's my problem.

Is there a way to match every route that ends with `ajax/get-categories` , so that both `upload/ajax/get-categories`  and `edit-mod/ajax/get-categories`  will work?

Let me know if you need any more code, I think I've included everything that is relevant to the problem.

Comment: http://docs.slimframework.com/routing/get/

Comment: Are you using a template engine?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with Slim framework. But I looked up in the documentation and I think that's not how you should pass parameters to the GET request.

in your route, change your code to something like this:

```
$app->get("/ajax/get-categories/:gameID", function($gameID) use ($app, $User, $Game, $Mod){
    // You can use the query string $gameID here...
    var_dump($gameID);
    // Do other stuff here...
});
```

In your JavaScript file:

```
// I assume in there is a gameID variable in your JavaScript.
$.get("ajax/get-categories/" + gameID, function(data) {

    //Do something with data    
});
```

Tell me if it works.

See the documentation [here](http://docs.slimframework.com/routing/get/).

Answer (score 0):

```
$app->get("/:segment/ajax/get-categories", function($segment) use ($app, $User, $Game, $Mod){

    //Fetch data and echo it
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have worked with Slim Framework ;)

Look, this is how I have managed to make Ajax work with Slim framework.

First, you have to declare the routes **both** *get* and *post* (when I first tried declaring *post* only, it didn't work):

GET:

```
$app->get('/your/url',$permission(),function() use ($app){
  //here you can check whether it is an ajax call
})->name('your.url');
```

POST:

```
$app->post('/your/url',$permission(),function() use ($app){
    //get the data:
    $request    =   $app->request;/*getting post data*/
    $var1       =   $request->post('var1');
    $var2       =   $request->post('var2');
    //echo '| For log and testing purposes you can echo out the gotten values. Var1: '.$var1.'. Var2: '.$var2;
    //DO YOUR STUFF here, for example, database processing with Eloquent ORM
    $saved=$user->save();
    if($saved){ echo '[success]';}else{echo '[error]';}/*http://stackoverflow.com/a/27878102/1883256*/
})->name('your.url.post');
```

Now, from the view side, make your ajax like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    /*Referencias: https://www.codecourse.com/forum/topics/use-jquery-ajax-post-with-the-authentication-series/527*/

        /*Permissions*/
        $(function() {
            $('#your_element').change(function(){
                var var1 = this.val1;
                var var2 = this.val2;
                console.log('Value1 is: '+var1+' and value2 is: '+var2);

                $.ajax({
                    data: {var1: var1,var2: var2,{{ csrf_key }}: "{{ csrf_token }}"},
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    headers: { "cache-control": "no-cache" },
                    url: "/your/url" //add ../your/url if needed
                });//ajax end
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

That's it.

- It is also important that you send the csrf token if you're using it in your forms.