# laravel . How can I judge the results of ORM

Tags: php, laravel

example:

```
$example = new Model();
$example->name = 'abc';
$example->save();
```

How can I judge the results of ORM?
Like this?

```
if($example->save){
    ...//do someting
}else{
    ...//do someting
}
```

But,I think it's wrong.Because,`$example->save()` will return an object。So,the`else{}` can't run forever.How can I judge the results of ORM?

Thanks for everyone.

Comment: I must be new or something. But, what is _juage_?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! vvv oh k

Comment: @CamW sorry ,it's judge

Comment: Are you trying to check whether model is saved or there is an error? If yes then you can place this block in try-catch block.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if laravel model got saved or query got executed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27877948/check-if-laravel-model-got-saved-or-query-got-executed)

Comment: @ShaluSinghal  Only recently started to learn,I don't know what I should do next.

Comment: @SoulKeep Okay. Then what exactly you want to do?

Comment: @ShaluSinghal <code>if($example)</code>,the $example should be a boolean. In ORM ,<code>save()</code> will return an obj.Can I check the result like this: <code>if($example->save()){}else{}</code>.

Comment: @SoulKeep `save()` returns a boolean. You can see for yourself in the [source code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L1453-L1489). Why do you think it returns an object?

Comment: @patricus Then I try again

Comment: @patricus Thanks,I have set a uniqueness field  in my database.So,I get an error but not an correct obj.

Comment: @SoulKeep Laravel will throw an exception for that. You'll need to wrap your save it a `try`/`catch` block in order to handle that.

Comment: @patricus Thanks.Can I filter the same request in validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**save()** will return a **boolean**. So you can either do:

$saved = $example->save();

```
if(!$saved){
    // something
}
```

Or directly save in the if:

```
if(!$example->save()){
    // something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `insert()` method which returns `true` or `false`:

```
$inserted = Model::insert(['name' => 'abc']);
    ...//do someting
if($inserted){

}else{
    ...//do someting else
}
```

Or, you could use `try... catch` clause:

```
    try
    {
        Model::insert(['name' => 'abc']);

        ...//do someting
    }
    catch(\Exception $e)
    {
        ...//do someting else
    }
```

You can try to do this:

```
$example = new Model();
$example->name = 'abc';
$example->save();
if ($example) { ... }
```

But it's not safe, because you can get error in this part and you'll not be able to catch it:

```
$example->name = 'abc';
```