# Does laravel save() method throws exception?

Tags: php, database, laravel, exception, transactions

I have a little question here. This is my code:

```
DB::beginTransaction();
    try{
        $created = new TransportTypeColumn();
        $created->name = $translated_ids[0];
        if(!$created->save())
            throw new \Exception("failed saving transport type column");
        DB::commit();
        return response()->json(['success'=>'Property has been created successfully', 'data'=>$created],200);

    }catch(\Exception $e){
        DB::rollback();
        return response()->json(['error'=>'Something went wrong, please try later.'], 500);
    }
```

so do I need this piece of code ? :

```
if(!$created->save())
            throw new \Exception("failed saving transport type column");
```

or does it throws exception itself if save() function doesn't succeed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if laravel model got saved or query got executed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27877948/check-if-laravel-model-got-saved-or-query-got-executed)

Comment: You can set `$saved = $created->save(); $saved === true;`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`save` returns a boolean, you need to check if the save was successfull or not, but unless there is a mysql error you won't get any exceptions.

Comment: If save() doesn't work, that means there is mysql error? so I always get exception.. isn't that right?

Comment: I mean is it possible that save() returns false but there is no mysql or any other exceptions?

Comment: I can't think of one right now, but i found this https://laravel.io/forum/09-08-2014-save-function-doesnt-work-and-does-not-output-an-error , it is always good to check if the record was saved anyway.

Answer (score 4):

I know this question has already an answer, but for people who stumble upon this and want an exception to be thrown, you could use the method `saveOrFail()` instead of `save()`.

```php
DB::beginTransaction();
try{
    $created = new TransportTypeColumn();
    $created->name = $translated_ids[0];
    $created->saveOrFail();
    
    DB::commit();
    return response()->json(['success'=>'Property has been created successfully', 'data'=>$created],200);
} catch(\Exception $e) {
    DB::rollback();
    return response()->json(
        ['error'=>'Something went wrong, please try later.'],
        $e->getCode()
    );
}
```

This method is around since at least Laravel 5.5 and you can find more information about it in the [docs](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_saveOrFail)